# Missing scipy functions in fftpack

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I installed scipy with `easy_install scipy`, but Python cannot find the [scipy.fftpack.dct()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.dct.html#scipy.fftpack.dct) function. What did I do wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

scipy.fftpack.dct is available in scipy version [0.10.dev](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/fftpack.html), but is missing in [version 0.9](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.9.0/reference/fftpack.html). So you probably have version 0.9 or earlier.